# how to control mobile brightness with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, controls, selector, brightness

I need to control brightness with this circular selector which I don't know it's name -if you can tell me the name of widget I will be thankful- so how to control the brightness?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HGI.jpg)

```
onChanged(value){
     setState((){

    });
}
```

Comment: You can check out this library https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_screen

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.light 
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
```